# Is there a way to tell if a Monero node is on, even though it is not public facing and behind a router?

Tags: monerod, daemon, raspberry-pi

I want to setup `monerod` on a Raspberry Pi and put it behind a router, but I it won't be public facing nor have any forwarded ports. Is there a way to tell if my Raspberry Pi is active with `monerod` still running? Is there a way to mark my node with some type of alias and look it up in a Monero node database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without forwarded ports, no. Unless of course you also owned the node it was syncing from, in which case you could check that other nodes connected peers.